# Oracle query optimization recommendation

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

Below query is just taking long time and the below predicate is used only to get unique records, as such was wondering is there a different way to rewrite the same query without calling the below predicate multiple times, to get the unique ID.

```
select max(c.id) from plocation c where c.ids = y.ids and c.idc = y.idc)
select max(cr.id) from plocation_log cr where cr.ids = yt.ids and cr.idc = yt.idc)
select max(pr.id) from patentpr where pr.ids = p.ids and pr.idc = p.idc)
```

**My full sample query**

```
SELECT to_char(p.pid) AS patentid,
       p.name,
       x.dept,
       y.location
  FROM patent p
  JOIN pdetails x ON p.pid = x.pid  AND x.isactive = 1
  JOIN plocation y
            ON y.idr = p.idr
           AND y.idc = p.idc
           AND y.id = *(select max(c.id) from plocation c where c.ids = y.ids and c.idc = y.idc)*
           AND y.idopstype in (36, 37)
   JOIN plocation_log yt
            ON yt.idr = y.idr
           AND yt.idc= y.idc
           AND yt.id = *(select max(cr.id) from plocation_log cr where cr.ids = yt.ids and cr.idc = yt.idc)*
           AND yt.idopstype in (36,37)
WHERE
      p.idp IN (10,20,30)
   AND p.id = *(select max(pr.id) from patent pr where pr.ids = p.ids and pr.idc = p.idc)*
   AND p.idopstype in (36,37)
```

Comment: Could you give details about the table definition ?

Comment: If you rephrase the query using window functions instead of correlated subqueries it will run much faster. Does your version of Oracle support windows functions (`OVER` clause)?

Comment: Oracle supports window analytic functions since 8i :) I don't think anybody uses older versions

Comment: Show us the indexes on the tables.

Comment: @TheImpaler Thank you. I like the advise, do you happen to have a sample with window functions instead of correlated subqueries for my instance, to get the unique Id please ?

Comment: @Parfait, sorry fixed above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider joining to aggregate CTEs to calculate `MAX` values per group **once** as opposed to rowwise `MAX` calculation for every outer query row. Also, be sure to use more informative table aliases instead of `a, b, c` or `x, y, z` style.

```
WITH loc_max AS
  (select ids, idc, max(id) as max_id from plocation group ids, idc)    
 ,   log_max AS    
  (select ids, idc, max(id) as max_id from plocation_log group by ids, idc)
 ,   pat_max AS
  (select ids, idc, max(id) as max_id from patent pr group by ids, idc)

SELECT to_char(pat.pid) AS patentid
       , pat.name
       , det.dept
       , loc.location
  FROM patent pat
  JOIN pdetails det
    ON pat.pid  = det.pid  
    AND det.isactive = 1
  JOIN plocation loc
    ON  loc.idr = pat.idr
    AND loc.idc = pat.idc
    AND loc.idopstype IN (36, 37)
  JOIN loc_max                              -- ADDED CTE JOIN
    ON  loc.id  = loc_max.max_id
    AND loc.ids = loc_max.ids 
    AND loc.idc = loc_max.idc
   
  JOIN plocation_log log
    ON  log.idr = log.idr
    AND log.idc = log.idc
    AND log.idopstype in (36,37)
  JOIN log_max                              -- ADDED CTE JOIN
    ON  log.id  = log_max.max_id
    AND log.ids = log_max.ids
    AND log.idc = log_max.idc

  JOIN pat_max                              -- ADDED CTE JOIN
    ON  pat.id  = pat_max.max_id
    AND pat.ids = pat_max.ids 
    AND pat.idc = pat_max.idc

WHERE pat.idp IN (10, 20, 30)
  AND pat.idopstype IN (36, 37)
```

Comment: I like this approach. Apparently the explain plan shows bit higher cost than my earlier query. Not sure why, but indeed your approach makes sense.

Comment: Consider indexing the `JOIN` columns. Regardless of explain plan which can show more steps due to CTEs and new `JOIN`s, does query overall run slower?

Comment: Yes. It is indeed slow. I have ended rewriting the query in a different way and seem working. Thx for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

As commented by The Impaler, one option is to use analytic functions instead of correlated subqueries. The idea is to rank records within subqueries using `RANK()`, then filter in the outer query (join conditions or `WHERE` clause).

Consider:

```
SELECT to_char(p.pid) AS patentid,
       p.name,
       x.dept,
       y.location
  FROM (SELECT p.*, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY ids, idc ORDER BY id) rn FROM patinet) p
  JOIN pdetails x ON p.pid = x.pid  AND x.isactive = 1
  JOIN (SELECT y.*, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY ids, idc ORDER BY id) rn FROM plocation y) y
            ON y.idr = p.idr
           AND y.idc = p.idc
           AND y.idopstype in (36, 37)
           AND y.rn = 1
   JOIN (SELECT y.*, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY ids, idc ORDER BY id) rn FROM plocation_log yt) yt
            ON yt.idr = y.idr
           AND yt.idc= y.idc
           AND yt.idopstype in (36,37)
           AND yt.rn = 1
WHERE
   p.idp IN (10,20,30)
   AND p.idopstype in (36,37)
   AND p.rn = 1
```